# Issue on dc.js when update/redraw linechart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm very new on javascript and dc.js. I have tried to remove and update new data in linechart after click the button. However, I got some problems when the line chart is redrawn. Some areas appeared and overlaped the area of the graph. Here is the picture of the line chart before and after redrawn
[image: Original version]
[image: After updated the new data]
[image: After switched the data back to the previous data]
Could anyone help me with this issue? I'm really appreciated every answer.

Thank you!

Here is my code

```
   **Just sample code, I have 5000 objects in my array**
    var data2 = [{"year": 2010,"total": 1}, 
                {"year": 2010,"total": 1},
                {"year": 2000, "total":1},
                {"year": 2000, "total":1},
                {"year": 1950, "total":1},                    
                {"year": 1950, "total":1},
                {"year": 1987, "total":1},
                {"year": 1987, "total":1},                    
                {"year": 2000, "total": 1}];
     var dataCrossfilter = crossfilter(data2);
       var yearDimension = dataCrossfilter.dimension(function (d) {
           return d.year;
           });
       var yearGroup = yearDimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
           return d.total;
           });     

       var yChart = dc.lineChart("#yChart");

        yChart.width(960)
        .height(300)
        .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40})
        .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([1800,2020]))
        .dimension(yearDimension)
        .group(yearGroup)
        .renderArea(true)           
        .brushOn(true)
        .transitionDuration(1500)
        .elasticY(true)
        .elasticX(true)
        .xAxis();

    dc.renderAll();
```

//// for load button

```
var load_button = function(data) {
            return function load_it() {
                    dataCrossfilter.remove();
                    dataCrossfilter.add(data);
                    dc.redrawAll();
            }
        }

    button1 = load_button(data1);
    button2 = load_button(data2);
```

Thank you so much! I really appreciate every answer.

Comment: I believe you, but I can't seem to reproduce this with so little data.  Here is my fiddle of what you provided, with another dummy data set of the same size: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/becxo0fv/5/ - maybe you can add to it to make it break?

Comment: Did you try clear your chart with with `yChart.resetSvg();` and the redraw it fully?

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort your data by date. AMCharts suffers the same malady.